# psql client auto completion in edit mode using vi

Tags: vim, syntax, autocomplete, vi, psql

In **psql** client, you can enter input edit mode with `\e`, witch calls an editor, witch in my case is vim (similar to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>-<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> in bash). Is there a way to achieve same syntax auto completion capabilities in this edit mode as simply typing in psql gives (autocompletion support for syntax and object names like tables, schemes, sequences, types and etc... )?

Answer (score 1):

Have you searched [vim.org](http://www.vim.org/)?

- [dbext.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=356) provides (among other features) completion:

> dbext ties into Vim dictionary feature.  You can complete table names, procedure names and view names using the i_CTRL-X_CTRL-K feature

- [psql.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=952) provides syntax highlighting. The script is quite old, though; don't know whether all keywords are supported